# remove bottom margin between two navbars - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have two `navbars` in my web application. However, there's a space between these two `navbars` as seen in the image below.

[image]

I have tried `.navbar{margin-bottom: 0px}` with no luck.

Here's my HTML

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  .navbar{margin-bottom: 0px}
</style>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar-no-margin">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinmodal">Sign in</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupmodal">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-->
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar-no-margin">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinmodal">Sign in</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupmodal">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-->
    </nav>
```

Comment: is this what are you trying to acheive http://www.bootply.com/dIc9lyYLyy

Comment: Hi @user2771150, just try to remove navbar-fixed-top class and set margin, of both, to 0 0 0 0...

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar{margin-bottom: 0px !important}
```

Adding the `important` to the end of the rule overwrites the default styling for the `margin-bottom` in `bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `body`'s `padding-top` to `50px`.

```css
body {
 padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-no-margin">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinmodal">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupmodal">Sign up</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!-- /.container-->
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar-no-margin">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signinmodal">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupmodal">Sign up</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!-- /.container-->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position property to relative instead of fixed and the margin bottom to 0.

```
.navbar-default {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Below is a Jsfiddle displaying the output.
https://jsfiddle.net/niteshp27/vkntcdbf/